# jQuery: If API Load success, do function

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, jquery-load

Im working with a search flight API and I would like to set few settings when the API is loaded.

Here is how the API is loaded:

```
skyscanner.load('snippets', '1');  
function main(){  
    var snippet=new skyscanner.snippets.SearchPanelControl();  
    snippet.setCurrency('GBP');  
    snippet.setDeparture('uk');  
    snippet.draw(document.getElementById('snippet_searchpanel')); 

    }  
skyscanner.setOnLoadCallback(main);
```

This is what I tried but doesn't seem to work:

```
skyscanner.load('snippets', '1', function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            if (textStatus == "success") {
                alert(test);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alert(test);
```

Where is `test`? maybe it should be `alert("test")`
UPDATE:
OK, I've just looked at skyscanner's API:http://api.skyscanner.net/api/ajax/documentation.html
here is the load function:

```
skyscanner.load(<i>moduleName, moduleVersion, optionalSettings</i>)
```

it seems that the 3rd parameter is not for onload event.
You could just test:

```
skyscanner.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    alert("test");
});
skyscanner.load('snippets', '1');
```

Comment: To elaborate, the way your code is written "test" is a function call, which is probably not a function. You probably meant to pass the string "test."

Comment: @RyanTM How did you came to the conclusion that '"test" is a function call'?

Comment: I have not come to that conclusion.

Comment: @RyanTM OK, maybe I misunderstand your comment,my poor english..:P

Comment: Actually you know what, I was being dumb. Of course it's not a function call it doesn't have parens after it. I should have said variable reference.

Comment: @wong2 Thanks. Although it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other 'hacky' way of doing it? Using the success command?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like SkyScanner already has an onload callback, and you've set it to "main()", wouldn't you just put your code where it needs to be (perhaps at the end) of that function?

I don't know the sky scanner api, so I don't know if their "load()" function takes a third parameter. It looks as if it might not, since they apparently provide the separate function setOnLoadCallback().

Comment: Fair enough. What did you try and what did it do?

Comment: Well I tried skyscanner.setOnLoadCallback(main, alert("test")); and it was alerting before the content loaded. I also added alert at the end of the main function. Again, it was alerting before the content was shown. I am trying to think of a hacky solution around it. Something like, if .some-class is visible then do the function. But doesn't seem to work either. Still is alerting before the content is shown. During the loading phase of the API, there's a <p> Loading </p> shown. I am thinking to alert when that is displayed to none...

Comment: ...  but I'm sure that will have many problems in the future. Is not as accurate.

Comment: Again, we don't have the API, so I don't know if "skyscanner.setOnLoadCallback(main, alert("test"));" is even valid syntax.

Comment: If snippet.draw() is asynchronous (if that function sets up an AJAX content load and then returns immediately -- which would be common for JavaScript), as is implied by your results, you may need to dig deeper: set up a loop with a timer and check every 200 milliseconds or some such to see if document.getElementById('snippet_searchpanel') has content (if it starts out blank) or the placeholder content has been replaced if there is placeholder content there.